# Oracle VM VirtualBox - cannot load system

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

installed Ubuntu on VM and I've used it for 2-3 weeks. Everything was working but today...

I try load my machine with Ubuntu but it gives me an error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  — Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    — Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    — Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  — Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/6134075f-a24a-4714-8208-5740d9339e60 does not exist. 
Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.13.3 built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs)_
```

How can I repair my guest OS?